# How can I make big angular single page application with asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've worked with AngularJS on a small sample project to learn basic things. Now I wanna make a real big application and I want to make it on a single asp.net view using WebAPI calls and loading AngularJS views. The problem is that I have no idea, how to handle with loading/unloading html views. I want to see, how to make real single page application not a small examples. Thanks for any posts, examples, docs, thoughts. I would better like asp.net mvc examples.

Comment: This will get you started, and includes a template that uses BreezeJS and Angluar: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example CRUD App in AngularJS with Java:

http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/restful-crud-with-angularjs/

Another One to learn basics of it:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/08/use-angularjs-to-power-your-web-application.html

Using .Net with videos:

http://jphoward.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/end-to-end-web-app-in-under-an-hour/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/657139/A-Book-Store-Application-Using-AngularJS-and-Asp-N